# Bucles For anidados en C

Tags: c

Buenos días,

Estoy empezando muy poco a poco en C, intentando aprender bien desde la base. Llevo ya demasiado tiempo dándole vueltas a un script sencillo, ya que no acabo de entender el por qué de su output, que es el siguiente:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

El script es este:

```
int main() {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

No consigo comprender por qué a partir de la segunda iteración los valores de `j` e `i` se alejan, cuando en ambos casos el incremento es de +1 tanto para i como para j. 
Seguramente será de las preguntas más tontas que se hayan planteado por estos foros, pero de verdad que por más vueltas que le doy no lo entiendo X)

Saludos y gracias !

Comment: Cuando i se inicializa, j imprime tantos asteriscos como el valor de i y termina la iteracion del bucle anidado. Luego printf("\n") hace un salto de linea, termina el bucle e i se incrementa.
Una vez que se imprimieron 5 filas de asteriscos el programa finaliza.

Comment: El bucle i sirve para indicar el número máximo de asteriscos a imprimir.
El bucle j sirve para imprimir los asteriscos pertinentes.
Esto para que el programa no tenga errores y se ejecute de de manera correcta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes dos bucles:

- El bucle `i` sirve para indicar el número máximo de asteriscos a imprimir
- El bucle `j` sirve para imprimir los asteriscos pertinentes.

Además los bucles son anidados, es decir, por cada iteración del bucle `i`, el bucle `j` realizará un recorrido completo desde `0` hasta el valor de `i`, lo que se podría indicar como `[0,i]`. Este intervalo también lo podemos expresar así `[0,y+1)` (cerrado por la izquierda y abierto por la derecha, lo que indica que el valor `y+1` no se incluye en el rango) y esa expresión es la que voy a utilizar más adelante.

Intenta resolverlo con lápiz y papel y paso a paso:

- Primera iteración del bucle `i`: `i=0`, luego el bucle `j` iterará en el rango [0,1) *nota que el 1 no entra en el rango al ser un intervalo abierto*. El resultado es que solo se imprimirá un asterisco: `j=0`
- Segunda iteración del bucle `i`: `i=1`, luego el bucle `j` iterará en el rango [0,2). Esto permite imprimir dos asteriscos: `j=0 y j=1`
- Tercera iteración del bucle `i`: `i=2`. El bucle `j` iterará en el rango [0,3) lo que imprimirá tres asteriscos: `j=0, j=1 y j=2`
- ...

Espero que ahora entiendas mejor la lógica del algoritmo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por responder! Creo que ya lo tengo todo claro. La parte que no había comprendido bien es el valor en que empieza a operar cada iteración. Pensaba que el j=0 solo se aplicaba a la primera iteración, a partir de la cual el bucle iba iterando desde el último valor de j, [0,1), [1,2), [2,3)... Por eso no me cuadraba que se añadieran más asteriscos, ya que el valor de j siempre es i+1.

Answer (score 2):

Hola Oscar Dsflskdflskdfl.

Lo que hay dentro del primer bucle for se ejecuta con un valor inicial de i igual a cero, mientras el valor de i sea menor que 5 y a cada iteración el valor de i se incrementa en uno.

Lo que hay dentro del segundo bucle se ejecuta para cada iteración de i con un valor inicial de j igual a cero, mientras el valor de j sea menor o igual que el valor de i y a cada iteración el valor de j se incrementa en uno.

Fíjate en que el segundo for se ejecuta para cada iteración de i.

Como resultado se imprime un asterisco tantas veces como el valor de j pueda llegar a alcanzar, el cual viene limitado por i en cada iteración del primer for.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No entendia yo tampoco pero la explicacion de Cristian Rivas Gómez me ayudo mucho y creo que lo que cuesta trabajo ver es que cada vez que entra al segundo bucle for va a entrar y lo debe de completar, en la primera iteracion j = 0 y i = 0 entonces solo imprime un *. despues sale de este bucle y despues ingresa al primer bucle de nuevo, ahora i = 1 y al entrar al segundo bucle j = 0 de nuevo y i = 1 entoces puede ahora iterar dos veces y imprime dos ** porque j legara hasta valor 1 y j<=i. despues sale del segundo bucle e ingresa al primer bucle, ahora i= 2, entra al segundo bucle j = 0 y i = 2 entoces puede imprimir tress ***. y asi sucesiva mente.